# For AWX, is it possible to authenticate at the reverse-proxy layer?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, ansible-tower

I have an AWX set up with an Apache reverse proxy for SSL reasons.

I know AWX supports SAML/SSO natively. However, we have a standard SAML set up that we use with multiple other applications, where authentication is done at the Apache layer and the user's information is passed back into the application (X-Forwarded-User or some such).

Is it possible to do this with AWX? How would I pass user information back to it? I have been searching but not found anything yet.

Comment: AWX is "just" a Django application so if you can support it with Django, you should be able to plug it into AWX. I assume there's already some implementation of this for Django somewhere but if not it shouldn't be too hard to do.